# First order stochastic dominance and the absolute value of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, variance

Suppose I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ that take both positive and negative values  such that $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$, and the absolute value of $X$, i.e., $|X|$, first-order stochastically dominates the absolute value of $Y$, i.e.,  $|Y|$.

Does this imply that $X$ second-order dominates $Y$? If not, are there additional conditions (e.g., symmetry?) such that second-order dominance is implied? Any references would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: By second-order stochastic dominance you mean that $E[f(X)]\ge E[f(Y)]$ for any concave $f$?